# Misanderstanding how to proper use callback while filtering in php

Tags: php, filter, callback

I want to properly check the user data from a form in PHP. I'm using filter class. I need to use a callback function to check the password. To achieve this, I used this tutorial on twentieths point (callback filter): 
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html#21

However I still get this error:

> "Warning: filter_var(): First argument is expected to be a valid callback" error.

Here is my class :

```
class Callback {

private function validPasswd($sPasswd) {

        $r1 = '/#[A-Z]+#/';  //at least one uppercase
        $r2 = '/#[a-z]+#/';  //at least one lowercase
        $r3 = '/#[!@#$%^&*()\-_=+{};:,<.>]+#/';  // at least one special char
        $r4 = '/#[0-9]+#/';  //at least one number

        if (preg_match($r1, $sPasswd)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (preg_match_all($r2, $sPasswd)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (preg_match_all($r3, $sPasswd)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (preg_match_all($r4, $sPasswd)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (strlen($sPasswd) < 8) {
            return false;
        }
        return $sPasswd;
    }
}
```

and here's the part of my method:

```
    public function createAccountAction() {
    //get password from form to verification.
    $sPasswd = $_POST['password'];

    //prepare all values to be checked with a filter
    $aOptions = array(
        'first-name' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'last-name' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'login' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
        'password' => array(
            'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
            'options' => 'validPasswd'
        ),
        'email' => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
        'conf-email' => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
    );
    var_dump(filter_var($sPasswd, FILTER_CALLBACK, array("options" => array("Callback"=>"validPasswd"))));
```

namespace and use are correct. I think it's the way I call the method that is not good.

Comment: change `array("Callback"=>"validPasswd")` to `array("Callback", "validPasswd")`

Comment: I just tried it but still the same error.

Comment: try array("options" => array("Callback"=>array($this, 'validPasswd')))

Comment: Still not. Do you think that the sub-array in $aOptions is well written ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be giving the instance that the method should be called on and the method to be called.

If the `createAccountAction` method is defined in `Callback`:

```
return filter_var($sPasswd, FILTER_CALLBACK, ["options" => [$this, "validPasswd"]]);
```

If the `createAccountAction` method is defined elsewhere:

```
// Give Callback::validPasswd public access and...
return filter_var($sPasswd, FILTER_CALLBACK, ["options" => [new Callback, "validPasswd"]]);
```

Comment: This is it ! Thank you. And it's logical, but it seems that the tutorial linked above has something wrong at this chapter...